# Passing different value (link value) from VF page to VF component and display it on screen

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, custom-controller

I am new to SFDC and now need some help from you guys.

My requirement is:
I have multiple links on VF page. Clicking any of them will pass a value to to Component and display the value on page.

[image]

**Page: Home1**

```
<apex:page controller="CursorTest">

    <div id="divId">
        <c:Task1 /> 
    </div>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandLink value="#Tab1" action="{!Save}" reRender="divId">
            <apex:param value="3" assignTo="{!eolSec}"/>
        </apex:commandLink>
        <br />
        <apex:commandLink value="#Tab2" action="{!Save}" reRender="divId">
            <apex:param value="300" assignTo="{!eolSec}"/>
        </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Page Controller: CursorTest**

```
public class CursorTest {

    public String eolSec{ get; set; }

    public CursorTest() {

    }

    public PageReference Save(){
        system.debug('--eolSec: ' +eolSec);

        Task1 t = (Task1) Task1.class.newInstance();
        if(eolSec== '3'){
            t.setTaskId('Tab1');
        }
        else if(eolSec== '300'){
            t.setTaskId('Tab2');
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

**Component: Task1**

```
<apex:component controller="Task1" allowDML="true">
    <!-- <apex:attribute name="inTaskId" assignTo="{!taskId}" required="true" type="string" description="Id of task to be viewed" />
    -->

    <apex:outputtext value="Val: {!taskId}" />

</apex:component>
```

**Component controller: Task1**

```
public with sharing class Task1 {
    public String taskId;

    public void setTaskId(String val){
        this.taskId = val;
    }

    public String getTaskId(){
        return this.taskId;
    }



    public Task1(){
        if(taskId == null)
                taskId = '1234';
        else
            taskId = this.taskId;
    }
}
```

I want:

1. Clicking on `#Tab1` link, the page will show `Val: Tab1`
2. Then, clicking on `#Tab2` link, the page will show `Val: Tab2`

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with code below. I reused your commented `inTaskId` attribute on your Visualforce Component, and passed the selected tab value through it. Also, my code re-renders the actual component, and not the `div`.

For something more advanced you can read [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication) blog post that describes a pattern on how to implement the communication between Page Controller and the nested Visualforce Components.

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="CursorTest">

    <c:Task1 inTaskId="{!tabId}" id="componentId"/> 

    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandLink value="#Tab1" action="{!Save}" reRender="componentId">
            <apex:param value="3" assignTo="{!eolSec}"/>
        </apex:commandLink>
        <br />
        <apex:commandLink value="#Tab2" action="{!Save}" reRender="componentId">
            <apex:param value="300" assignTo="{!eolSec}"/>
        </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Page Controller**

```
public class CursorTest {

    public String eolSec{ get; set; }
    public String tabId {get; set;}

    public PageReference Save(){
        system.debug('--eolSec: ' +eolSec);

        if(eolSec== '3'){
            tabId = 'Tab1';
        }
        else if(eolSec== '300'){
            tabId = 'Tab2';
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

**Component**

```
<apex:component controller="Task1" allowDML="true">
    <apex:attribute name="inTaskId" assignTo="{!taskId}"
         required="true" type="string" 
         description="Id of task to be viewed" 
         default="1234"/>
    <apex:outputtext value="Val: {!taskId}" />
</apex:component>
```

**Component Controller**

```
public with sharing class Task1 {
    public String taskId {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Mind Blowing dude :-)